# Convert html to xml in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, xml

I am getting of a html  from a div which contains  HTML Controls here is my HTML

```
 <h4>Please add Here</h4>
                        <select class="form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" id="ddlcountry" ng-model="selectedListId">
                            <option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- Choose Category --</option>
                            <option label="List Option 1" value="1"></option>
                            <option label="List Option 2" value="2"></option>
                            <option label="List Option 3" value="3"></option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <label ng-show="SelectedComboValue==1" class="col-md-3 control-label">Enter Date</label>
                        <input ng-show="SelectedComboValue==1" placeholder="Date" ng-model="Date" ng-disabled="NoData" jqdatepicker="" required="" class="hasDatepicker ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" id="dp1517988090226">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <label ng-show="SelectedComboValue==1" class="col-md-3 control-label">No Data </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-show="SelectedComboValue==1" ng-model="NoData" ng-click="ClearData()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched ng-untouched">
```

I want result something like this

```
 <select>
<option label="List Option 1" value="1"></option>
<option label="List Option 2" value="2"></option>
<option label="List Option 3" value="3"></option>
<option label="List Option 4" value="4"></option>
</select>
```

I want to convert entire html into xml using angularjs so how can i do this using angular approach or in jquery.

Comment: You'd have to be more specific about your question. Like, what kind of result are you expecting?

Comment: Your HTML contains a `select` tag with four options. Why/how does your result get only two? Do you only want to extract the `select`component?